# Unable to click on hyperlink when running selenium webdriver script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've been trying to click onto the hyperlink which leads to a popup on the screen. For some reason it is not working, currently the html for the hyperlink is this:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="operating-hours left">Select Hours</a>`

Trying with this selenium code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Select Hours"))).click();
```

Also tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("operating_hours")).click();
```

Interestingly I am not getting any error either, just that the hyperlink is not clicked. 
[screenshot after running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqLjN.png)
After running the script, that is the screenshot.

Whereas the script should have opened this popup window
[popup that should open after running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVyyt.png)
@DebanjanB hope that clarifies the problem.

Comment: Please provide HTML code, and please format code to be more readable, please use code block, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared instead of `linkText` you can use either of the following approaches and [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.operating-hours.left"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='operating-hours left'][contains(.,'Select Hours')]"))).click();
  ```
- If you still unable to invoke `click()` on the desired element you can use [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) Class as follows:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.operating-hours.left")));
  //WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='operating-hours left'][contains(.,'Select Hours')]")));
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
  ```
- As an alternative you can use [executeScript()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method from the  [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) Interface as follows:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.operating-hours.left")));
  //WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='operating-hours left'][contains(.,'Select Hours')]")));
  (JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
  ```

Comment: tried both but no improvement.. thanks anyways @debanjanb

Comment: @JaffarLone `no improvement` doesn't throws any light on whats wrong happening. Can you update the question with your current code trials and error you are seeing?

Comment: well i am attaching two screenshots, since i am not getting any error logs from testNG or Eclipse, thats all i've got.

Comment: @JaffarLone Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: the second option is working, popup is finally opening on the main screen. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are several examples to click on link via different selectors:

**Click link by full text**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Link"));
linkByText.click();
```

**Click link by partial text**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("First"))
linkByPartialText.click();
```

**Click link by text using XPath**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='First']"));
linkByTextUsingXPath.click();
```

**Click link by partial text using XPath**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'ABC')]"));
linkByPartialTextUsingXPath.click();
```

Also if needed use explicit wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(selector));
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("some_link")));
element.click();
```

Hope this helps,